# creating LPCTSTR conversion operator

Tags: visual-c++

Trying to create LPCTSTR conversion operator for my class:

```
AuthData::operator LPCTSTR() const
{
    const char* k = "aaaa";
    return k;
}
```

Error: return value type does not match the function type

Why it don't match?

Answer (score 0):

If Unicode Character Set is enabled, LPCTSTR type is const wchar_t *.

@Edit
You can read about these types here:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/194768

Comment: In this project I use Multi-Byte

Answer (score 0):

1. In a Multi-Byte project, LPCTSTR is defined as LPCSTR, which is CONST CHAR*, so your code should compile (if it is in fact non-Unicode).
2. NEVER mix TCHARs with chars! At least - not without a conversion. Your declaration practically implies that TCHAR is defined as char, so why would you suggest to the readers that you are TCHAR-aware (since you are not)?